# Can EADemo send http request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, bluetooth, external-accessory

Can someone suggest if it is possible to modify the EADemo to send HTTP request (custom header and body). In the project I am working on, the external accessory will be receiving the data using http request.

The method which is for writing on EADemo is

```
- (void)writeData:(NSData *)data;
```

Comment: The only way I see it can be done is by creating raw http (header and body) from either NSString or CFHTTP and convert it to NSData and then send it. If anyone has another opinion and experience, please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found an example which I will be using but instead of GET I will use POST. Below is the example of GET request:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {
NSLog(@"stream:handleEvent: is invoked...");

switch(eventCode) {
    case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
    {
        if (stream == oStream) {
            NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                @"GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"];
            const uint8_t * rawstring =
                (const uint8_t *)[str UTF8String];
            [oStream write:rawstring maxLength:strlen(rawstring)];
            [oStream close];
        }
        break;
    }
    // continued ...
    }
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html